# Stirling numbers of the second kind with multisets

Tags: math, optimization, set, counting, discrete-mathematics

I was looking at [Stirling numbers of the second kind], which are the total number of ways to split a set of length n into k non-empty subsets, where order does not matter.(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html), and was wondering how to write a non-naive algorithm to compute

```
S(n, k {occurences of each element})
```

Where

```
S(6, 3, {1, 2, 3} )
```

would give the total number of ways a set with 6 elements in which 3 are the same element and a different 2 are another element (and 1 is its unique element) could be split into 3 non-empty sets, ignoring permutations.

There is a recursive formula for regular Stirling numbers of the second kind S(n, k), but unlikely to be a comparable function for multisets.
So what's an algorithm that could calculate this number?

Relevant question on Math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind-on-multiset), without a real method to calculate this number.

Comment: I think a more natural generalization is S(nu,kappa) where each is a partition. Nu is the multiset summing to n. Kappa is a partition of k, where each part of  is a collection of indistinguishable subsets (sub-multisets). The usual Stirling number of the second kind corresponds to the partitions n=1+1+1...+1 and k=1+1+1+...+1.

To recover your S(nu, k), sum over all partitions of k. 

If kappa has a part larger than the largest part of nu, then the count is 0.

Comment: With that generalization, there is a recurrence. It is simple when you add a part to nu of size 1, but more complicated if you add a large part.

Comment: @Douglas-Zare When you say to sum over all possible partitions of k, shouldn't I also have to sum over all possible Nu's?  
You said to make Kappa a sub-multiset, so the only possibilities are for it are limited by the factorization of k...I think.
Are there any bounds on the possible multisets for Nu beyond that each must sum up to n?

Comment: @Cimbali, can you link me to a paper/book/site that discusses/lists these formulas? And I'm more looking for a general way.

Comment: You don't need to sum over the partitions of n, but if you specify some number of subsets k, this corresponds to many kappa partitions. Each part of kappa represents a collection of identical submultisets of nu. For example, you could have nu = {6,3}, k=4. One possible kappa would be 3+1. One representative is {{A,A},{A,A},{A,A},{B,B,B}}. Another is {{A,B},{A,B},{A,B},{A,A,A}}. Another is {{A},{A},{A},{A,A,A,B,B,B}}. Yes, there are other constraints on the relationship between kappa and nu for there to be a nonzero count. So, if you are interested in some families of enumerations...

Comment: ... such as where nu is close to 1+1+1+...+1, the classical case of Stirling numbers of the second kind, you can bound the complexity of the recursion since you only need to consider a few kappas. However, I don't know whether cases like that are of particular interest to you.

Comment: Ok. I had misinterpreted your original comment to mean that each k must be 1+1+..+1 or 2+2+2+...+2.  
Can you explain how the representatives in your example correspond to the given kappa of 3+1?

Comment: In those examples, there were 3 submultisets with the same counts of As and Bs, and 1 submultiset that was different, hence the kappa of 3+1. Basically, if you drop some set of symbols, you induce a collection of submultisets on the restricted set of symbols. If you do this for a set of symbols and its complement, the kappa partitions are what you need to say how you might glue those induced collections together.

Comment: @robertkin Sorry that was about Stirling numbers of the second kind without multisets. When you say "occurrences of each element", do you consider them ordered or not ? That is, when you write {1, 2, 3}, do you mean a given element `a` in your set appears once, `b` twice and `c` three times ? Or do you also want to count for different mappings of set elements to multiplicities ?

Comment: Well, ridiculously late reply, but yes, {1, 2, 3} means a given element a in your set appears once, b twice and c three times